# Use a pool of coroutine workers or one coroutine per task with Semaphore

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Suppose I have one million web pages to download. Should I use a fixed number of coroutine workers to download them, or create a coroutine per url and use `asyncio.Semaphore` to limit the numbers of coroutines.

First option, fixed workers:

```py
async def worker(queue):
    while True:
        try:
            url = queue.get_nowait()
        except QueueEmpty:
            break
        await download(url)

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    for url in urls:
        await queue.put(url)
    workers = [worker(queue) for _ in range(10)]
    await asyncio.wait(workers)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Second option, use semaphore:

```py
async def worker(url, sema):
    async with sema:
        await download(url)

async def main():
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(10)
    workers = [worker(url, semaphore) for url in urls]
    await asyncio.wait(workers)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: when you test those two what difference are you noting? Did a remote server always respond on the 1st option?

Comment: If you are using AIOHTTP, another solution is to use a single shared `Session`  initialized with a `TCPConnector` with a limited number of opened simultaneous connections (`limit` parameter). See [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#limiting-connection-pool-size) for details. Then, you just have to `asyncio.gather` the N concurrent downloads tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach (`Queue` + 10 tasks) won't equally distribute the workload (1M urls downloads) between fixed number of coroutines/tasks. When you'll add  simple ordinal indices to identify each worker during processing you may note that some workers will hold/occupy the queue for a longer time so some workers downloads a hundreds of urls and some - tens of thousands urls.

    While the 2nd approach (`Semaphore`) ensures that only a fixed number of urls will downloaded at a time by fixed number of active workers.

    The above should also count on a remote server max connections limit (in case if a large proportion of urls have same origin).